# How to run `pip install -e .` programatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this question has been asked before.

How can I run equivalent of `pip install -e .` in python code itself? Or install directly from the egg or `setuptools` if it's possible.

Currently I can programatically generate the `*.egg_info` for a project that specifies `pyproject.toml` or `setup.py` in this manner:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

distro: Distribution = setup(script_args=['egg_info'])
```

Can i extend the above code to run `pip install -e .` with the generated egg directory? Is that possible?

Comment: the officially recommended way is to use `subprocess` to call the CLI

Comment: I don't know this library, but you can do what you want in this way.

with this method:

You import the os library and then call the system function and execute your command code

Comment: @emanuel It's a default library in python. installed automatically with venv

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?